# The minimize icon is gray

Tags: macos, window-manager, icon

It happens sometimes that the yellow circle in the top left of the windows, for minimizing, becomes gray for some windows. In particular it is gray for Finder, Safari, Calendar, iTerm2, Xchat Azure, Chrome, VirtualBox, and is still yellow for other windows, for example Mail, KeePassX, NoteBook, FreeMind, DjView, Lyx.

Obviously, when it is gray it is disabled.
The situation comes back to normal apparently without any reason.

The OS is Mountain Lion 10.8.5, and this is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sort of medications installed, something that changes the look/behaviour of Finder or the Dock?

Comment: @AndrewU.: no, nothing of that kind, I think.

Comment: And does this happen with various apps randomly or certain apps randomly? Is there any line to be drawn between moments that you have noticed the issue? How does a restart affect the behaviour? Does Finder restore your previous session upon login?

Comment: @AndrewU.: no, i tried to pay attention, but I cannot see any pattern.

Comment: Have you already tried reinstalling the OS? And what about the other portions to my comment? I left a lot of question marks there ;)

Comment: @AndrewU.: no, I have not tried to reinstall, and I have no intention to do it: I can live with this little problem. Sorry, I pressed enter too early, preparing a comment to answer other questions

Comment: What's so bad about reinstalling the OS (I am not talking about deleting all of your files)? Does Finder restore your previous session upon login?

Comment: Don't bother reinstalling the whole Operating system. I have that behavior as well (sometimes) and it is not a problem as far I know. Try the cmd-M!

Comment: @AndrewU. Q1: it seems random and also apps involved seems to be random. Q2: no, i cannot say. Q3: there is no need to restart, the problem goes away after some minutes or so. Q4: i restart very rarely, but when I do it, finder restore correctly the previous session, only VirtualBox and iTerm2 pose some problems to the restart.

Answer (score 2):

Well now I have to take a stab at this with the information and comments you have provided. I am going to guess that the OS is damaged, probably the WindowServer is screwed up (http://www.macinside.info/process.php?name=WindowServer).

This can be resolved with a reinstall of the OS. You should have any data loss but of course make sure you have an active backup of all files just to be on the safe side.

To test though you could turn off the OS function of restoring previous sessions and then restart the computer holding down the shift key. With the shift key held until you see the spinning gear. This starts your system in Safe mode where only Apple daemons are allowed to run. WindowServer is a part of the OS and if it is indeed damaged then the issue will appear (after some time maybe) in a Safe OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to reinstall and the Safe mode is unusable, so I switched back to the normal mode before the problem appear.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, my Chrome 65.0.3325.181 window had its orange Minimize button grayed out and disabled.

Solution that worked for me to restore the orange Minimize button:

- go full screen (green button)
- leave full screen (green button again)